# ValueError: Shapes (29, 1) and (42, 1, 29) are incompatible [Keras]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I'm trying to use keras to build a model that takes 42 inputs and outputs 1 of 29 classes. But when I try to fit my model, I get that error message.

```
    from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
    
        Y_train_cat = to_categorical(Y_train, 29)
        Y_test_cat = to_categorical(Y_test, 29)
        Y_val_cat = to_categorical(Y_val, 29)
        
        train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train,Y_train_cat))
        test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test,Y_test_cat))
        val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val,Y_val_cat))
    
    from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
    early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience = 2)
    
    model = Sequential([
            Dense(units = 102, input_shape = (42,1), activation = 'relu'),
            Dense(units = 56, activation = 'relu'),
            Dense(units = 29, activation = 'softmax') 
            ])
    
    
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model)
    
    model.fit(x = train_dataset,
              batch_size = 30,
              epochs = 10,
              shuffle = False,
              verbose = 2, 
              validation_data = val_dataset,
              callbacks = [early_stopping_monitor]
              )
```

The shape of train_dataset is

```
<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((42,), (29,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float32)>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Dense Layers have limitation for 2D arrays, you should first Flatten data to a vector, then feed it through dense layers. Otherwise, it will process data in last dimension and you will get other dimensions in the output.

In your case input shape is `(42,1)`. So, the output shape of last layer would be `(42,29)`, and it is incompatible with the labels you have provided. So, consider to change the input shape. Either you can squeeze your data from `(42,1)` to `(42)` and modify input shape argument, or you can add a Flatten layer as the first layer like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(42,1)),
            Dense(units = 102, activation = 'relu'),
            Dense(units = 56, activation = 'relu'),
            Dense(units = 29, activation = 'softmax') 
            ])
```

UPDATE: Also batch your data to add a batch dimension like this:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 30
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train,Y_train_cat)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Whole code with random dataset with shapes like yours:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

X_train = tf.random.uniform((100,42,))
Y_train = tf.random.uniform((100,), dtype=tf.int32, minval=0, maxval=29)

Y_train_cat = to_categorical(Y_train, 29)  
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train,Y_train_cat)).batch(30)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(42,1)),
            Dense(units = 102, activation = 'relu'),
            Dense(units = 56, activation = 'relu'),
            Dense(units = 29, activation = 'softmax') 
            ]) 

model.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model)
model.summary()
model.fit(x = train_dataset,
              batch_size = 30,
              epochs = 10,
              shuffle = False,
              verbose = 2, 
              )
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the help, I'm not sure if this is a trival problem but when I try to flatten the layer, I get this error: <
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 42 but received input with shape (42, 1)> I am unsure of how to alter the dataset variable to squeeze the input into (42) shape.

Comment: Excuse me. I forgot to tell you, also batch your data. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is my model now:

model = Sequential([
        Flatten(input_shape = (42,1) ),
        Dense(units = 102, activation = 'relu'),  # Always for first layer
        Dense(units = 56, activation = 'relu'),
        Dense(units = 29, activation = 'softmax')  # Probability for each output class
        ])

Comment: Thanks for the information about batch sizes! Unfortunately the same error cropped up even with adding the new stuff: < ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 42 but received input with shape (42, 1)>

Comment: Please tell me `X_train` and `Y_train` shapes. I considered them as `(n_samples,42,1)` and `(n_samples,1)` respectively.

Comment: `X_train` is shape of (n_samples, 42) and
`Y_train` is shape of (n_samples, )

Comment: I don't know why you still get error. But I can run the code with random data without any error.  Even With the shapes you have. I will add my complete code, which works for me, with random data. You may compare it with your code. Hope to be helpful.

Comment: Hi thanks! I realised it was because I did not put .batch() for the validation set. May I ask when I call model.predict(x=X), what type of data would X be? I tried putting in a numpy array but I got     <ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 42 but received input with shape (None, 1)>

Comment: The numpy array was of size (42,) which is weird that it had the shape (None,1)

Comment: The input data could be any type of arrays. You can read more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit). Most commonly mistakes is not about data type, but about the data shape. It expects the dimension of input data (x) as `(batch_dimension, your_input_shape_specified_in_first_layer)`. Because first dimension vary, it specifies it with `None`. But the other dimension should be always the same.

Comment: For example, if it show you `(None,1)` dimension, it means, it expects a batch data with any batch size (`None`) which each sample in the batch has shape like `(1,)`. Or if you specify the `input_shape=(42,1)`, then it expects you pass data with `(None,42,1)` shape.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to overcome the none error by passing X through `model(X)` instead. Thanks for your help my model seems to work fine now!!